# What's the most efficient way to add a series to an existing time series?

Tags: r, time-series

I want to column-bind a new series to an existing time series. Here's the example from help(ts):

```
z <- ts(
  matrix(rnorm(300), 100, 3), 
  start = c(1961, 1), 
  frequency = 12
)
```

And here's the only way I've found to add to the series while preserving names AND time:

```
z1 <- ts(
  cbind(
    z,
    runif(dim(z)[1])
  ),
  start(z),
  names = c(dimnames(z)[[2]], 'unif')
)
```

I suspect there's a cleaner way to do this (much the way data.frames work?).

Comment: Unfortunately there is no clean way to deal with names with the ts class time-series. I personally dislike using other classes because I'm suspicious of the split of time series into a lot of different standards (besides, for regular complete time-series I think the datetime key/index is overkill). But I reckonize that the original methods for time-series can be sometimes be disappointing.

PS : in your example you forgot frequency = frequency(z)

Answer (score 3):

Convert to `xts` and `transform` (used `R 4.1.0` for the operator `|>`)

```
library(xts)
z1 <- as.xts(z) |> 
          transform(unif = runif(dim(z)[1]))
```

-output

```
> head(z1)
            Series.1   Series.2   Series.3      unif
Jan 1961  0.58124800  0.1510926  1.0826555 0.2552968
Feb 1961  1.15737740  0.8661810  0.3916422 0.5525945
Mar 1961 -0.23185935  0.2858634  0.8118146 0.3055733
Apr 1961 -1.72068316 -0.6347280  0.1287224 0.4017409
May 1961 -2.07815044 -0.5623785 -1.8947997 0.3404939
Jun 1961 -0.09922355 -0.6606838  1.2231682 0.5405788
```

---

Another option is `as_tsibble`

```
library(tsibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
as_tsibble(z) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = key, values_from = value) %>% 
    mutate(unif = runif(n()))
# A tsibble: 100 x 5 [1M]
      index `Series 1` `Series 2` `Series 3`  unif
      <mth>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>
 1 1961 Jan     0.581      0.151     1.08    0.632
 2 1961 Feb     1.16       0.866     0.392   0.698
 3 1961 Mar    -0.232      0.286     0.812   0.631
 4 1961 Apr    -1.72      -0.635     0.129   0.912
 5 1961 May    -2.08      -0.562    -1.89    0.750
 6 1961 Jun    -0.0992    -0.661     1.22    0.370
 7 1961 Jul     0.450      1.01     -0.0622  0.605
 8 1961 Aug     0.328     -1.28     -0.729   0.221
 9 1961 Sep     0.511     -0.675    -0.387   0.489
10 1961 Oct    -0.943      0.0116    0.00400 0.630
# … with 90 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, when you try to append a vector at the end of rows or columns, it takes time for R to do this job.
the most efficient way is to create an M*N empty matrix then try to fill it like this

```
dat <- matrix(NA,ncol = 10,nrow = 10000)
## for i'th row
dat[i,] = myVector
```

or for i'th column
dat[,i] = myVector

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case I think it makes sense to stick to a data.frame with a (first) column reserved for TIME, because for simple description and regression I really don't need any of the features of a time series object. This does mean keeping track of rows (i.e. when I diff(), etc.) but that's wise anyway. Thanks for your suggestions!